# Can having certain restrictions/rules make passcodes less secure?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, password-policy

Say I have a phone whose security is corporately managed, and this management demands that I use a 6 digit passcode to lock the phone. So far, so reasonable. This gives an attacker a possibility of 1,000,000 passcodes to try if they were to brute force. The phone locks for 5 minutes every time the passcode is entered wrong, too.

However, if I am expected to *never* use any sequential or repeating numbers, surely this reduces the space of possible codes by a huge amount? Thus making the phone easier to break into. Why would this policy be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the policy on sequential numbers is very defensive and concerns the following digit, and assuming that 9 is followed by 0, this reduce the number of available passcodes to 10*8^5=**327.680**

Which reduce the possibility to a subset containing 32.76% of the original possibilities, which is not that much different on a scale.

However, such a rule prevent the user from setting trivial passcodes such as 000000 or 123456 which are incredibly dangerous to set on a corporate phone as these are very common passwords that a potential malware will try to input.

In conclusion, the **risk** of reducing the number of available passcodes to chose from is **small** compared to the impact of letting the user set a trivial password.

Comment: The key component here, is that an attacker would not **start** with a brute force attack.  A dictionary attack (I.E. Trying very common patterns first) would immediately discover the common passcodes.